# Online Users Storing Elixir

Tags: erlang-otp, elixir, gen-server, elixir-mix

I am working on one chatroom [all to all] application in Elixir using OTP Genserver and getting messages from js client as user gets registered with their names as first phase. Now, just bit not sure what would be the best approach to store these names at my elixir server somehow and send regular updates to client with list of users online or database storage. Please suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with bitwalker that ETS is a good fit.

Here's a short summary of what I did in production. It wasn't a chat server, but a server push with a couple of thousand of users connecting via long polling. Pushed data was divided in some 50 categories, and users were able to choose which ones they want. At peak times the server pushed new messages each 2 secs, and processed > 2000 reqs/sec.

Essentially, I kept a `gen_server` for each user, where I held pending messages and user's configuration (basically a list of selected channels). This was beneficial with long polling, since user's data is decoupled from the user's request, so the data remains while requests are transient. However, I think this approach is also good for permanent connections, such as websockets, since there might still be occasional disconnections, and keeping a more stable user's data gives you a chance of resuming after reconnect.

Obviously, when a request arrives, you need to find the user specific process, and for this, ETS is a good fit, since you don't have a single process bottleneck. Instead of manually working with ETS, I'd recommend using [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) in conjunction with `via` tuples. Basically, when starting a user's gen_server, you can provide `name: {:via, :gproc, {:n, :l, key}}` where `key` is some custom key (arbitrary term) you make based on your internal user's id(`:n` and `:l` indicate a unique name on the local node). You can then use that same `via` tuple when issuing calls/casts, and `gen_server` will use `gproc` to find the corresponding process.

Finally, you need to have some timeout/disconnect logic to cleanup user processes. In my case, I simply terminated a user's process if there was no activity from the web layer (no end-user came for data in some time). Gproc will automatically remove entries for terminated process from its internal ETS table. It's probably best to supervise user processes under a `temporary` strategy.

I realize all of this is still a bit vague, but I hope it makes some sense. Keep in mind that this is not the ultimate pattern (there's no such thing of course), but I think it's a reasonable first attempt.

You may also want to take a look at [Phoenix web framework](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix) that has an interesting pub-sub facility in form of`Topics`. I didn't try this out myself yet, but it seems interesting, and may even simplify some of the stuff I discussed above, or at least help for pushing notifications from chatroom to all users.

Comment: oh great, many thanks for your suggestion !!, i gave a small TEST try to ETS after you & bit walker suggested. But when users are sending their names to registration on my handle_info, it is getting stored only by one user. When some other user tries to get register server gets crashed. So ETS do maintain state? or may be i am implementing it in wrong way. Please suggest.                                                      def create(user) do
  :ets.new(:call_table, [:named_table, :bag])
  :ets.insert(:call_table, {:user, user})
 end
 def lookupuser do
  :ets.lookup(:call_table, :user)
 end

Comment: Your ETS is by default protected which means only the process that owns (creates) the table can write. You need to make it public, or serialize all writes through the owner process. Take a more detailed look at :ets.new docs (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new-2). Also, keep in mind that ETS table is released when the owner (by default creator) process terminates, so be careful where you create the table. If you're putting pids in the table, it's really better to use gproc which does this and all sort of other goodies.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good use case for [ETS](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html).

A simpler approach might be to use an Agent to store the online users information, but it depends quite a lot on what you need from the storage mechanism you choose.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, however i did not get whole message. Can you suggest with some same code (if possible) my handle_info function looks like this :                                                                            def handle_info(message, state) do
  
  {a,b} = message
  username = b[:body]
     {:noreply, state}
 end